# Total number of nodes in a tree given number of branch and depth

Tags: recursion, time-complexity, big-o

Is it correct that the number of nodes in a tree, given maximum branching factor `b` and maximum depth `d` is O(b^d)?

I'm practicing some `backtracking` problems and trying to analyze the run time complexity of the solution, which traverses through all nodes in the "backtracking tree"

Comment: How many nodes can there be at the root? Just the one. How many nodes can there be just below the root? At most `b`. How many nodes can there be below that layer? At most `b` times `b`. How many layers do you have? At most `d`. Your result can be proven fairly straightforwardly using [mathematical induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the maximum number of nodes will be b^d (b on first level, then b*b on level 2, etc d time), but the actual number of nodes may vary if the tree is not full. For maximum analysis of complexity that is a correct assumption however.